# Error " getoutputstream () ya ha sido llamado para esta respuesta " al abrir pdf

Tags: java, jsp, pdf, file

Tengo este código que lo que hace es abrir un PDF que está en una ruta.
Al abrir este archivo, efectivamente lo abre, pero en consola me muestra el error de `getoutputstream() has already been called for this response` y es molesto porque puede generar errores futuros.
No he logrado hacer que no ocurra ese error y por eso busco ayuda.

```
        <%@page import="java.io.FileInputStream"%>
        <%@page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true"%>
        <%@ page language="java" contentType="application/pdf; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
        <%@ page import= "java.io.*" %>
        <%

            boolean error=false;
            try {
                String nombreArchivo=request.getParameter("doc");
                Archivos archivo= new Archivos();
                FileInputStream ficheroInput = new FileInputStream("C:\\archivo\\archivo.pdf");
                int tamanoInput = ficheroInput.available();
                byte[] datosPDF = new byte[tamanoInput];
                ficheroInput.read( datosPDF, 0, tamanoInput);

                response.reset();
                response.resetBuffer();
                response.flushBuffer();
                response.setHeader("Content-disposition","inline; filename=unrt.pdf" );
                response.setContentType("application/pdf");
                response.setContentLength(tamanoInput);
                response.getOutputStream().write(datosPDF);

                ficheroInput.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                error=true;
            }
        %>

        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
        <html>
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Visor PDF</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <% if(error){
        %>   
            <h1>Ocurrió un error al cargar el archivo</h1>
        <%}
        %>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Chequea esta respuesta de stackOverFlow en ingles : creo que es la solucion a tu problema : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1776142/getoutputstream-has-already-been-called-for-this-response

Answer (score 0):

Pon esta linea al final:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
```

antes del `ficheroInput.close();`

Comment: Hola, se agradece la respuesta. Pero estaría bien que la complementaras con alguna explicación. Cómo y por qué funciona? Así será de utilidad para otros desarrolladores